# nodejs net.createServer large amount of data coming in

Tags: node.js, actionscript-2

I have nodejs listening on tcp port and gets content from Flash XMLSocket. If I try to push a lot of data in one message from flash (`XMLSocket.send(long_message)`) I always end up with event `stream.on("data", function(d) {` fired while I want it to happen when entire message is transferred.
Flash's XMLSocket transfers data as UTF8 encoded string terminated with null byte.
How can I control my message consistency?

### UPDATE

I've found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437012/how-to-keep-node-js-from-splitting-socket-messages-into-smaller-chunks). But there is no clear answer. I know the end of my message should be null byte, but could you please give me an example on how to store incomplete message and avoid overlapping with next/concurrent message

### UPDATE2

After maerics's answer I've done something like

```
    var server = net.createServer(function(stream) {
    var dataBlock = "";
    stream.on("data", function(d) {
            processChunk(d);
    });

    function processChunk(data) {
            var chunks = data.split("\0");
            while (chunks.length > 1) {
                    if (dataBlock.length > 0) {
                            dataBlock += chunks.shift();
                            processIncompingMessage(dataBlock);
                            dataBlock = "";
                    }
                    else {
                            processIncompingMessage(chunks.shift());
                    }
            }
            dataBlock += chunks.shift();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your eventual solutions looks reasonable, but just wanted to point out that it assumes a message will never be > 2 chunks.

Comment: Why? If chunks.length will be, say, 5 then we'll loop in while loop 4 times, every time shifting first element of array until chunks.length becomes 1. And after that if it equals to blank string - dataBlock.length next time would be 0, else it will append parial message to dataBlock

Comment: Yeah, whatever issue I saw yesterday, I don't see it now, so I was probably just misreading something. Sorry :P Just remember to do setEncoding on the stream like mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would do (tested):

```javascript
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
  var msg = ''; // Current message, per connection.

  conn.setEncoding('utf8');

  conn.on('message', function (m) {
    console.log('MESSAGE: ' + m);
  });

  conn.on('data', function (data) {
    msg += data.toString('utf8');

    if (msg.charCodeAt(msg.length - 1) == 0) {
      conn.emit('message', msg.substring(0, msg.length - 1));
      msg = '';
    }
  });
});
```

Note that it is possible that multiple null separated messages could be encoded in a single data chunk, so you should expand this example to separate the data by null characters and process each one separately.  Also, you might want to process the final, potentially incomplete message on the connection `'end'` event.

Comment: What if d contains end of one message and part of another one? Could it happen?

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko: ya, just updated my answer to mention that contingency.  In this case you should scan the data for nulls and emit a message for each string of enclosed text.

Comment: So read data somehow in while loop and look for null byte? If found - append to previous part and handle and start next buffer? Maybe split method somehow?

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko Probably a good idea to use setEncoding on the stream instead of .toString on each chunk, otherwise you might get part of a multi-byte char.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: good point; out of curiosity, even if we do use `setEncoding()` is there a chance that the data could contain only the first null byte of a multibyte character?  Or does the client software (or node.js, or the OS, etc.) guarantee that wide characters cannot be truncated?

Comment: @maerics If you do setEncoding, the 'data' emitted is already a string, so it will only emit valid characters. You can read more in my anwser here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046071/problems-with-parsing-utf8-characters-in-request-body/9046164#9046164